# Plot 3D each component of a given function (in Matlab/Octave)

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to plot each component of a function f over a square Q=[0,1]x[0,1]

```
   f   = @(x,y)  [-0.5*x + 0.25  ;  -0.5*y + 0.25];
```

If I have a scalar function (with one component) g:

```
   g   = @(x,y)  -0.5*x + 0.25;
```

plot is easy with the following:

```
   xxx=[0:0.01:1];
   yyy=[0:0.01:1];
   [xxx yyy]=meshgrid(xxx,yyy);
   surfc(xxx,yyy,g(xxx,yyy))
```

But, how can I plot each component of a vector function f over the same set Q?

```
   f   = @(x,y)  [-0.5*x + 0.25  ;  -0.5*y + 0.25];
```

Comment: how do you envisage the output? f_x represented as the z-axis height and f_y represented as a colormap? or as a 2D vector field plot with vectors at each x,y position defined by f_x, f_y?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy visualising the results as a vector field, then you can do it like this:

```
f = @(z) -0.5 .* z + 0.25;
[X, Y] = meshgrid (0:0.01:1, 0:0.01:1);
quiver (X, Y, f(X), f(Y));
```

If your f_x and f_y components aren't necessarily identical, you can split them (meshgrid step implied):

```
f_x = @(x) -0.5 .* x + 0.25;
f_y = @(y) -0.5 .* y + 0.25;
quiver (X, Y, f_x(X), f_y(Y));
```

If you really, *really* need to have them both as a single non-vectorizable function, then you can get around this using arrayfun:

```
f   = @(x,y)  [-0.5*x + 0.25  ;  -0.5*y + 0.25];
quiver(X, Y, arrayfun(@(x) f(x,0)(1), X), arrayfun(@(y) f(0,y)(2), Y));
```

Result:

[image]